# C# baseurl on injection of httpClient

Tags: c#, http, dependency-injection, httpclient

I'm using dependency injection with HttpClient and I'm trying to figure out how to set a baseurl, but can't seem to figure it out.

I'm doing it this way:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostUser(User user) { 
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.UseServices();
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var service = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();

        return await service.PostUser(user);
 }

class UserService : IUserService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public UserService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostUser(User user)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(BASEURL, user);
            return response;
        }

    }
```

I register in this way:

```
public static class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static void UseServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHttpClient<IUserService, UserService>();

        }
    }
```

So I want to use the BASEURL in the above, but how can I pass it with the httpClient?

Comment: Where do you want to get base url from?

Comment: I want it to be accessible from the httpClient in my constructor.

Comment: How do you register HttpClient in DI? As singleton on application startup?

Comment: Ive added the way I register.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
    public static class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static void UseServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHttpClient<IUserServicee, UserService>(
                              client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("YOUR_BASE_ADDRESS"));

        }
    }
```

Method overload takes `Action<HttpClient>` as an argument so it's void and you can mutate your `HttpClient` instance in the way you want.

Comment: But how would I send the baseurl from my PostUser function?

Comment: If you need to set the base address when you call your PostUser function, you can pass the base address as a parameter? That's why I asked how and when you want to set it

Comment: @Recusiwe Typically, you set the base URL from outside your service. In your service, you can just pass a relative path. F.e. the BaseAddress could be set to `https://api.server.com/api`, then `_httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("user", user)`

Comment: that's exactly what my answer is about. You set base address when you register your http client

Comment: I tried that, but that hands me an error. I'll add it shortly.